# Slow TTFB with ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, jplist

This issue is also posted on: https://github.com/1rosehip/jplist/issues/276
But no answer from the developer.

I have implemented the Jplist - Jquery Data grid controls (see jplist dot com) on my development server and i have some issues with the performance. Example page (which is slow): https://prijsvergelijk.dimeshop.nl/aanbieder/Alternate/

For example when you change the order, this will take 5 seconds too load. I did some debugging and saw that the waiting time is in TTFB (Time to First Byte). I Have checked database query (mySql), but this is very fast.

I don't know how to fix this. Can somebody give me some help how to fix this? If you need something ask for it.
Hopefully this can be solved so that i can push this to production :-)

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved. Was performance issue in server code.